# No SQL result output from sql executed from bash

Tags: bash, sql

When executing an SQL from a shell like this, the sql result output isn't printed. How do I do it ?

> mysql -uroot -p < /root/queries.sql

Edit: When the content of the sql is a SELECT, I do see the output. When it's an UPDATE, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

When executing the `mysql` binary from the command line, the `-p` option, unless given an argument, causes `mysql` to wait for `STDIN` (e.g. the user typing the password and hitting enter).

You can either execute:

```
cat /root/queries.sql | mysql -u root -p
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p'myPasswordHere' < /root/queries.sql
```